# Exchange Online -- hyperlink to new email equivalent to mailto:

Tags: email, exchange, mailto

I'd like to be able to enable people to quickly send an email from their existing Outlook Exchange Online account with information filled in -- currently we're using `mailto:` links with recipient and message body filled in, but there are issues around which accounts people are logged into.

Is there a hyperlink that we can use?

mailto for local email client: `mailto:jam@jam.invalid`

gmail and google apps: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?source=mailto&to=jam@jam.invalid`

yahoo mail: `https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?To=jam@jam.invalid`

outlook exchange: ???

It's OK if this URL isn't portable across different email domains.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113198/how-to-create-links-to-compose-an-email-in-gmail-as-well-as-outlook-specifically

Answer (score 1):

Like so for O365/Exchange (work accounts):

```
https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?to=user@domain.com&subject=hello%20world&body=goodbye
```

Or for Outlook.com (personal accounts), try:

```
https://outlook.live.com/mail/deeplink/compose?to=user@domain.com&subject=hello%20world&body=goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

The mailto: URL is specific to the email domain that you are using, so it may not work for other email domains.